# If $ f:I=[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow X$ is bounded by an integrable function so it is Bochner integrable?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X=(X,||\cdot||)$ be a Banach space and $f:I=[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow X$ a function such that
$$ ||f(s)|| \leq g(s),\: \forall \: s \in I$$
for some $g:I \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} $ (Riemann) integrable.

With this I can conclude that $ f $ is Bochner integrable?

Comment: Yes if you assume the obviously necessary condition that $f$ is Bochner-measurable because a Bochner-measurable function is Bochner integrable iff it's norm is integrable.

Comment: Without any assumption on $f$ this is not true. The characteristic function of a non-measurable subset is bounded but not integrable.